# stack inline 2 models each other which have a common onetoone field to another model

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class User:
    ....

class Profile:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Job:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have stackinline profile and job within the user model directly.
but trying to stackinline *Job* under *Profile* model didnt work

Comment: You should do those kind of things in the `admin.py` not in the `models.py` files

Comment: Can you show your form